# '/' in update dictionary throws error in firebase

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I'm doing a database migration on firebase using a cloud function triggered on an http endpoint. 
I'm basically going through the database and assembling an update dictionary to then call ref().update(dict). I've done this before and had no problems with it, but because of the new db structure, i need to do something like

```
teamUpdates['/calendar/' + visibleMonths[month] + '/' + matchId] = minifiedEvent
```

The problem with this, is that for some reason, firebase is not parsing the '/' as the path, and thus gives me an error:

> First argument  contains an invalid key (/calendar/February 2018/-L5n0GL4OjV3fnRg2wYV). 
>   Keys must be non-empty strings and can't contain ".", "#", "$", "/", "[", or "]".

In the docs it uses the '/' character to define paths, and I've successfully used it before, so I don't know what the problem is. Any ideas?

This is what they do in the docs:

```
var updates = {};
updates['/posts/' + newPostKey] = postData;
updates['/user-posts/' + uid + '/' + newPostKey] = postData;
```

What I think is happening is that I have a function that returns an object with some of the updates, and then add that to a second update object (just to have my function cleaner, I build the object in another function and return it). Something like this:

```
// This function returns the 'teamUpdates' object
const team = teamMigration(data[teamId])
// This is the dictionary that database.ref().update() gets called with
updates['/teams/' + teamId] = team
```

UPDATE 1: I refactored the code to scrap the whole 'teamUpdates' dictionary and directly nest everything under updates['/teams/' + teamId].

Looks ugly but works! The problem seems to be that firebase doesn't parse '/' past the first level as a path, and instead treats them as keys, which obviously fails.

I'm gonna wait to see if a firebase team member verifies this before I answer the question. Thanks for the help everyone!

Comment: The [examples shown here](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2015/09/introducing-multi-location-updates-and_86.html) don't have a leading `/`. For example: `updates['posts/' + newPostKey] = postData;`.  Have you tried that?

Comment: Yeah, I didn't have that in the beginning either, added it after I saw [the docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#updating_or_deleting_data). I think it makes no difference.

Comment: Although not listed as one of the invalid chars, I wonder if the space in `February 2018` is the problem?

Comment: Just throwing this out there, what about using `database.ref('/').update()` to explicitly start at the root?

Comment: We have spaces already in some keys, and it doesn't cause an issue, so I doubt it.

Comment: doesn't database.ref() always mean the root? Is there a need to specify it?

Comment: Spaces are fine, as are having multiple segments. Can you reproduce the problem with a single, hardcoded path? That'll make it easier to figure out.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen
I ended up directly nested everything under the `updates` dictionary and it worked, so my guess is the firebase SDK doesn't parse '/' as a path past the first level of the object passed to `update()`

Comment: It *does* parse multiple `/` and I've used it to write at arbitrary depths. That's why I'm asking for a simpler repo, so I can more easily see what's different about yours.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen We'll I tried it with the docs example:
`updates['/user-posts/' + uid + '/' + newPostKey] = postData;`
If postData is a dictionary with paths like `postData['images/ + imageId] = imageURL;`, it'll fail and complain about the key (images/asdf1234) because it has the char '/'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code is a modification of @Frank's example to demonstrate the style of update object construction that @kylar13 used.  This fails with the "invalid key" error:

```
  var db = admin.database();
  var ref = db.ref("50281844");
  var updates = {};
  updates['posts/newPostKey'] = "newKeyValue";
  // create a child map with '/' in key      
  var subUpdate = {};
  subUpdate['uid/newPostKey'] = "newKeyValue";
  // add it to the update map
  updates['user-posts'] = subUpdate;

  ref.update(updates)
```

@kylar13: As you indicate in the update to your post, it appears the `/`s in object keys can only be in the root-level object, and cannot be in sub-objects.  Perhaps Frank will take a look at this and confirm.

Comment: That is indeed correct Bob: the database parses the JSON, turns the (top-level) keys into paths, and essentially calls `set()` for each of those. There is no recursion of that process.

Comment: This is exactly what was happening to me! It seems only the top level '/' get parsed as paths. Thanks for all the help guys!!

Comment: @kylar13 please accept an answer so that other users can see that this question contains a solution.

Answer (score 2):

I just ran this code in a local node environment:

```
var admin = require('firebase-admin');
var serviceAccount = require("./stackoverflow-3d9889aaeddb.json");
admin.initializeApp({ credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),databaseURL: "https://stackoverflow.firebaseio.com"});

var db = admin.database();
var ref = db.ref("50281844");
var updates = {};
updates['posts/newPostKey'] = "newKeyValue"
updates['user-posts/uid/newPostKey'] = "newKeyValue"
ref.update(updates)
```

And it wrote this to the database:

```
{
  "posts" : {
    "newPostKey" : "newKeyValue"
  },
  "user-posts" : {
    "uid" : {
      "newPostKey" : "newKeyValue"
    }
  }
}
```

The multiple slashes in the keys seem to work fine here, so I'm note sure why they wouldn't work for you.

See https://stackoverflow.firebaseio.com/50281844.json

Comment: I provided example code in my answer that I hope clarifies the failure case.  Please take a look.